# Hashmap not adding new Keys and Values - Javascript

Tags: javascript, hashmap

I'm new to this, so go easy please lol.

I've got a hashmap, and I'm attempting to dynamically add new keys and values. I'm doing this in a for loop, but for some reason, the only key and value that gets added to the hashmap is the last one found by the for loop.

Here's my code:

```
//HASHMAP BEGINNING HERE;
var newKey;
var newValue;

var MQHash = {};

for (var c = 0; c < lines.length; c++) {
    if (lines[c].match(/\.\w+\s\{|\.\-\w+\s\{|\.\w+\-\w+\s\{/)) {
        console.log("It works!");
        console.log(lines[c].match(/\.\w+\s\{|\.\-\w+\s\{|\.\w+\-\w+\s\{/));
        //Saving the match as newKey
        newKey = lines[c].match(/\.\w+\s\{|\.\-\w+\s\{|\.\w+\-\w+\s\{/);
        console.log("NEWKEY", newKey);
    }

    if (lines[c].match(/\{(.*)(.*)\}/)) {
        console.log(lines[c].match(/\{(.*)(.*)\}/));
        //Saving the match as newValue
        newValue = lines[c].match(/\{(.*)(.*)\}/)[1];
        //Pushing them both into the hashmap
        //MQHash.push(newKey, newValue);
        //ALSO TRIED IT THIS WAY
        MQHash[newKey] = newValue;
    }
}
```

This is what the output of the final hashmap looks like:

```
"Final Version" Object { .bg-color {: " width: 400px; " }
```

And I know that there are supposed to be more values within that key.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide an example input (`lines`)?

Comment: So `lines` will have in it, for example `@media screen and (max-width: 600px) and (min-width: 420px) {
 .bg-color {
  width: 500px;
 }
}`

Comment: Have you tried to manually force one of those missing key/values pair into your `MQHash` to check whether it accepts your keys/values? Something like `MQHash["@media"] = "screen and (max-width: 600px) and (min-width: 420px) { .bg-color { width: 500px; } }";`

Comment: Have you also tried to explicitly `console.log(newValue)?` because I see that `newValue` is different from what you log just before

Comment: Yh, I've tried them both. It works when I manually force them in, but this isn't what I'm after. Yes, `newValue` is slightly different, because that creates an array, so I'm only interested in the second line of the array, hence the `[1]`.